# Java input encoding

Tags: java, input, encoding, utf-8, bufferedreader

So I've been working on a basic Java application which reads data from a text file via buffered reader, and fill it into a swing JTable.

The code works fine in NetBeans, the special letters are shown perfectly both in console and the Form itself.

The problem is after I build the project and place it somewhere on my harddrive and run it thru the generated .jar, it messes up the reading from the file, and weird letters appear... Łä¤˘

I tried these:

```
BufferedReader bfr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\update.txt"), "UTF-8"));
```

... and ...

```
BufferedReader bfr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\update.txt"));
```

I hope You can help me.

Comment: Have you tried to write/read the file using `java.nio`?

Comment: have you checked BufferedWriter charset? Can you post code for that

Comment: @deHaar Thanks! It worked using Files.readAllLines() :)

Comment: Very good... I would prefer `java.nio` wherever possible.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with @deHaar 's tip (java.nio)